# CLR Runtime version from CLR header

Tags: clr, dumpbin

when i use dumpbin \clrheader to one assembly,
i found following content-
Since i complied under .net4.5,How the CLR verion would be 2.05?

Dump of file SampleApp.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

clr Header:

```
          48 cb
        2.05 runtime version
        2080 [     668] RVA [size] of MetaData Directory
       20003 flags
               IL Only
               32-Bit Required
               32-Bit Preferred
     6000001 entry point token
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Resources Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of StrongNameSignature Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of CodeManagerTable Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of VTableFixups Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of ExportAddressTableJumps Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of ManagedNativeHeader Directory
```

Summary

```
    2000 .reloc
    2000 .rsrc
    2000 .text
```

Comment: Looks like it just lifts the `MajorRuntimeVersion` and `MinorRuntimeVersion` from the CLI Header (ECMA-335 Partition II Section 25.3.3). Unfortunately the specification doesn't seem provide any guidance of how they should be set or used other than being 'currently' 2 and 0 respectfully (6th edition from June 2012 - the most recent version I have seen). I suspect it has more to do with how the header should be interpreted rather than the .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

Because what's referred to as the "runtime version" by this tool is not actually the runtime version and has little to do with it. It's a misnomer. You cannot use `dumpbin` to print the actual runtime version. Instead, you can use `ildasm` which refers to the runtime version as the "metadata version." You can find the metadata version in the manifest of the assembly. For .NET 4.x, the runtime version is 4.0.30319.